# Is there a Text Element that doesn't have input/border/non-white cell color by default?

Tags: javascript, html

So I want some sort of element that isn't treated as an input, but I can update via Javascript (e.g. `$("someElement").value = "Updated Text"`) However while you can use `readonly` or `disabled`for stuff like text inputs, they still have a non-white cell color and a border by default. I tried a search for "text element with no input", but didn't find anything useful regarding some form of text element that met what I was looking for. Does such a text element exist?

Comment: could a `span` be what you are looking for? ie: `$('#spanId').text('Updated Text');`

Comment: Yep, that was the solution! Thanks!